# Разработать java ee приложение. С чего начать

Tags: java, java-ee

Меня поджимает время, поэтому хочу знать все и сразу (прошу простить и понять).

Нужно разработать приложение, умеющее:

1. Принимать http get и post запросы выводя содержимое бд (удаленный
   сервер) на сайте (обычный сайт с бд)
2. Сервис, в фоне посылающий get и post запросы на
   удаленный ресурс, полученный ответ обрабатывается и заносится в бд

Я знаю основы java и разрабатывал приложения под Android, но с java ee не знаком. Подскажите учебники, которые позволят реализовать вышеперечисленное без литья воды.

Comment: обязательно Java EE? или подойдет любой фреймворк? лучше переформулировать вопрос - так как на этот нельзя дать объективный ответ.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вы готовы порекомендовать начинающему фреймворк, который работает не на сервлетах, а на совершенно отвлеченном стеке?

Comment: @etki я просто уточнил у ТС какие у него требования относительно фреймворка.

Comment: Вообще, я из коллектива Android-разработчиков, но могу посоветовать разбираться с Hibernate (библиотека для БД) и Spring (как я понял, в нем есть практически все для написания таких приложений).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй Spring 4 + Hibernate4. Вот в принципе простой гайд. `http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial`

Единственный напряг будет с конфигурацией xml. Вообщем гайдов море по spring mvc + hibernate.
По поводу сервиса который посылает get и post, можно реализовать обычный планировщик @Scheduled в spring. Например каждые 5 минут будет создаваться http client или просто httpconection и уже дальше в нём обрабатываешь полученные данные.

По учебникам, если время поджимает не думаю что есть время всё это переваривать. "Spring 4 для профессионалов" например

Comment: Зачем напрягатсья с конфигурацией XML?

Answer (score 1):

[jdbc](http://www.javenue.info/post/java-jdbc-api) + [servlets](http://devcolibri.com/4284) Первое для доступа к базе данных, второе для отображения на странице. Спринг и Хибернейт то дольше разбираться.